# Importing an AWS project from git to local machine

Tags: java, eclipse, git, amazon-web-services, github

I think this might be a silly question, but I am confused about how to import some any project from git to Eclipse.

git source is https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-kinesis-data-visualization-sample

I can't import the project as general java project I need to import this as an aws java project.

Answer (score 0):

It's a maven project.

Make sure you have maven eclipse plugin (m2e) installed. Then it as maven project. m2e plugin will take care of the setup. (It may requires to download additional depended jars from internet. Make sure you have internet connection)

Comment: I have installed m2e plugins. but the problem is after clicking AWS Toolkit I am not getting from where to import that project.

Answer (score 0):

I guess when time of cloning repository it will ask like import existing project and create new project like that At that time yo need to click import existing project